# Error: compute.VirtualMachineExtensionsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=400

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have problem during my setup of servers in azure for terraform. The code is as below and the error i am facing i cannot fix. Do you have any experience with them :

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "techtaskaster" {
  name     = "${var.prefix}-rg"
  location = var.location
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "myvnet" {
  name                = "${var.prefix}-vnet"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.techtaskaster.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.techtaskaster.location
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "mynet" {
  name                 = "${var.prefix}-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.techtaskaster.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.myvnet.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.5.0/24"]
}

resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "nsg" {
  name                = "${var.prefix}-nsg"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.techtaskaster.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.techtaskaster.name
}

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "externalip" {
  count               = var.vm_count
  name                = "${var.prefix}-pip-${count.index}"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.techtaskaster.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.techtaskaster.name
  allocation_method   = "Dynamic"
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nic" {
  count               = var.vm_count
  name                = "${var.prefix}-nic-${count.index}"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.techtaskaster.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.techtaskaster.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "internal"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.mynet.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    public_ip_address_id           = azurerm_public_ip.externalip[count.index].id
  }
}

resource "random_password" "windows_password" {
  length  = 40
  special = true
}

resource "random_string" "windows_username" {
  length  = 12
  special = false
}

resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "srv" {
  count               = var.vm_count
  name                = "${var.prefix}-vm"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.techtaskaster.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.techtaskaster.name
  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.nic[count.index].id]
  size                = var.vm_size
  admin_username      = random_string.windows_username.result
  admin_password      = random_password.windows_password.result

  os_disk {
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
    offer     = "WindowsServer"
    sku       = "2019-Datacenter"
    version   = "latest"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_lb" "las" {
  name                = "${var.prefix}-lb"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.techtaskaster.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.techtaskaster.name

  frontend_ip_configuration {
    name                 = "public"
    public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.puip.id
  }
}

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "puip" {
  name                = "${var.prefix}-lb-public-ip"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.techtaskaster.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.techtaskaster.name
  allocation_method   = "Dynamic"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "srv0" {
  name               = "customScriptExtension"
  virtual_machine_id = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.srv[0].id
  publisher          = "Microsoft.Compute"
  type               = "CustomScriptExtension"
  type_handler_version = "1.10"

  settings = <<SETTINGS
{
  "script": "hostname && uptime"
}
SETTINGS

  protected_settings = <<PROTECTED_SETTINGS
{
  "script": "hostname && uptime"
}
PROTECTED_SETTINGS
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "srv1" {
  name               = "customScriptExtension"
  virtual_machine_id = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.srv[1].id
  publisher          = "Microsoft.Compute"
  type               = "CustomScriptExtension"
  type_handler_version = "1.10"

  settings = <<SETTINGS
{
  "script": "hostname && uptime"
}
SETTINGS

  protected_settings = <<PROTECTED_SETTINGS
{
  "script": "hostname && uptime"
}
PROTECTED_SETTINGS
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "srv2" {
  name               = "customScriptExtension"
  virtual_machine_id = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.srv[2].id
  publisher          = "Microsoft.Compute"
  type               = "CustomScriptExtension"
  type_handler_version = "1.10"

  settings = <<SETTINGS
{
  "script": "hostname && uptime"
}
SETTINGS

  protected_settings = <<PROTECTED_SETTINGS
{
  "script": "hostname && uptime"
}
PROTECTED_SETTINGS
}
```

Error:

```
compute.VirtualMachineExtensionsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="BadRequest" Message="Multiple VMExtensions per handler not supported for OS type 'Windows'. VMExtension 'customScriptExtension' with handler 'Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension' already added or specified in input." │ │   with azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.srv0, │   on main.tf line 94, in resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "srv0": │   94: resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "srv0" { │ ╵ ╷ │ Error: compute.VirtualMachineExtensionsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="BadRequest" Message="Multiple VMExtensions per handler not supported for OS type 'Windows'. VMExtension 'customScriptExtension' with handler 'Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension' already added or specified in input." │ │   with azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.srv1, │   on main.tf line 114, in resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "srv1": │  114: resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "srv1" { │ ╵ ╷ │ Error: compute.VirtualMachineExtensionsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="BadRequest" Message="Multiple VMExtensions per handler not supported for OS type 'Windows'. VMExtension 'customScriptExtension' with handler 'Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension' already added or specified in input." │ │   with azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.srv2, │   on main.tf line 134, in resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "srv2": │  134: resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "srv2" { │ ╵ `
```

I try to see in the web different suggestion but non of them is working

Answer (score 0):

```js
Message="Multiple VMExtensions per handler not supported for OS type 'Windows'. VMExtension 'customScriptExtension' with handler 'Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension' already added or specified in input.
```

The above error is encountered when an extension with the same type '**CustomScriptExtension'** has already been created on the `VM`.

To resolve the issue, please `uninstall` the existing extension on the `VM` and then try to deploy again.

I have created three VMs, with an extension in each VM, using the following `Terraform` code

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
variable "prefix" {
  description = "A prefix for naming resources"
  type        = string
  default     = "venkat"
}

variable "location" {
  description = "The Azure region where resources will be created"
  type        = string
  default     = "East US"
}

variable "vm_count" {
  description = "Number of VMs to create"
  type        = number
  default     = 3
}

variable "vm_size" {
  description = "The VM size to use"
  type        = string
  default     = "Standard_DS2_v2"
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "techtaskaster" {
  name     = "${var.prefix}-rg"
  location = var.location
}
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "myvnet" {
  name                = "vm-vnet"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.techtaskaster.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.techtaskaster.location
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "mynet" {
  name                 = "vm-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.techtaskaster.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.myvnet.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.5.0/24"]
}

resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "nsg" {
  name                = "vm-nsg"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.techtaskaster.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.techtaskaster.name
}

locals {
  subnet_ids = tolist(azurerm_subnet.mynet[*].id)
}
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nic" {
  count               = var.vm_count
  name                = "${var.prefix}-nic-${count.index}"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.techtaskaster.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.techtaskaster.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "internal"
    subnet_id                     = element(local.subnet_ids, count.index)
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}

resource "random_password" "windows_password" {
  length  = 40
  special = true
}

resource "random_string" "windows_username" {
  length  = 12
  special = false
}
resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "srv" {
  count               = var.vm_count
  name                = "${var.prefix}-vm-${count.index}"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.techtaskaster.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.techtaskaster.name
  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.nic[count.index].id]
  size                = var.vm_size
  admin_username      = random_string.windows_username.result
  admin_password      = random_password.windows_password.result

  os_disk {
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
    offer     = "WindowsServer"
    sku       = "2019-Datacenter"
    version   = "latest"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "srv1" {
  name               = "CustomScriptExtension"
  virtual_machine_id = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.srv[0].id
  publisher          = "Microsoft.Compute"
  type               = "CustomScriptExtension"
  type_handler_version = "1.10"

settings = <<SETTINGS
 {
  "commandToExecute": "hostname"
 }
SETTINGS
}


resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "srv2" {
  name               = "CustomScriptExtension"
  virtual_machine_id = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.srv[1].id
  publisher          = "Microsoft.Compute"
  type               = "CustomScriptExtension"
  type_handler_version = "1.10"

settings = <<SETTINGS
 {
  "commandToExecute": "hostname"
 }
SETTINGS
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "srv3" {
  name               = "CustomScriptExtension"
  virtual_machine_id = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.srv[2].id
  publisher          = "Microsoft.Compute"
  type               = "CustomScriptExtension"
  type_handler_version = "1.10"

settings = <<SETTINGS
 {
  "commandToExecute": "hostname"
 }
SETTINGS
}
```

**Terraform Apply:**

[image]